# How to implement conditional conformance of a generic to a protocol in a function?

Tags: json, swift, generics, decodable

I have a basic networking function in swift as given below:

```
func fetchObject<T: Decodable>(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        if let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) {
            completion(object)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I would like to make the generic confirm to decodable protocol conditionally. It should return the object when the when generic confirms to Decodable and return the json serialized object when it doesn't. Something like below:

```
func fetchObject(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        if let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) {
            completion(object)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

How would I write a common function for both scenario?

Comment: Would it work to use `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data)` which returns a Boolean?

Comment: No, my requirement is to write single func for both scenario. Both scenario have a valid json data.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting some runtime type conformance checking that may be  useful.

1.

```
if let _ = object.self as? Decodable.Type {
                    print("\(object) conforms")
                }else {
                    print("\(object) does not conform")
                }
```

2.

```
        guard let data = data else { return }
           let myType = type(of: data)
           if myType.self == Decodable.Type.self {
                print("it's conforming")
            }else 
                {print ("it's not conforming")}
```

Comment: I tried this approach. But, was unable to combine the methods. I still had to write 2 methods where one returned any and other returned a generic object.